# How to automatically close the figure at the end of an animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display an basic animation using Python and Matplotlib through [`animation.FuncAnimation()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html). The animation is **non-repeating** and consist in a fixed (and pre-defined) amount of frames with some fixed interval beetween them. It is meant to run once.

Here's how a single random frame is supposed to look like:
[image: random frame]

The animation runs fine, but the figure doesn't close automatically after calling [`plt.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) since it is a blocking call.

I'm aware that the method `plt.show()` can be made into non-blocking call by writing `plt.show(block=False)`, but that doesn't completely solve my problem. I haven't been able to get any information here on StackOverflow and other sites regarding how the library dispose that information of this **event** or so, in order to allow me to call `plt.close()`.

I'm seaching for a pythonic way of doing this, instead of my current solution which is far from good. Here's my "solution":

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Animation settings
def animate(frame):
    grid_size = [10, 10]
    print('frame: {}'.format(frame)) # Debug: May be useful to stop
    grid = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=grid_size, dtype=np.uint8)
    ax.clear()
    ax.imshow(grid, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255) # Is the range [0, 255] or [0, 255)?

INTERVAL = 100
FRAMES_NUM = 10

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=INTERVAL, frames=FRAMES_NUM, repeat=False)

plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(float(FRAMES_NUM*INTERVAL)/1000) # Not pythonic
plt.close(fig)
```

1. Can anyone show me a pythonic way of doing this?
2. Am I doing this all
   wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to use the animating function to decide when to close the figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

grid_size = [10, 10]
grid = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=grid_size, dtype=np.uint8)
im = ax.imshow(grid, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

# Animation settings
def animate(frame):
    if frame == FRAMES_NUM:
        print(f'{frame} == {FRAMES_NUM}; closing!')
        plt.close(fig)
    else:
        print(f'frame: {frame}') # Debug: May be useful to stop
        grid = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=grid_size, dtype=np.uint8)
        im.set_array(grid)

INTERVAL = 100
FRAMES_NUM = 10

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=INTERVAL, 
                               frames=FRAMES_NUM+1, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your animation function use `plt.close()`
For example if your last frame plotted was `iFrame = 9`
then:

```py
if iFrame == 9:
    plt.close()
```